# Seeing a guid as part of the simulator choices

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When i got to choose a simulator to run my app on in Xcode 6.1.1. I see a guid next to the simulator name.

For example the choices I see are:

iPad 2 (062B5AD7-65CD-4079-B06E-182A6D110DB4)

iPAD 2 (49DA9317-4493-4664-9c25-172A97CEFA41)

iPad 2 (FCF2A5C#-9460-4C22-A948-3633C876FC35)

How do i get rid of these guids?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you've created too many iPad 2 simulators (and similarly for the others that look that same way). The interface needs *some* way to distinguish them so it adds their UID. Just delete simulators in the Window > Devices interface until you've only got one of each desired device type/SDK.

Comment: That's the strange part.  I have never created my own simulator.  Thanks for the tip about window / devices.  I deleted the dupes and now the GUID is gone.

Comment: Well, I shouldn't have said "you". Or maybe I meant "you and Xcode, mostly Xcode while you were looking the other way"! I don't know how the multiple simulators actually got created.

Comment: You should take a look at  ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.default_created.plist to see which ones CoreSimulator created for your default set.  I'd be interested to know how the ones that *aren't* listed in .default_created.plist were created.  If you enabled debug logging, there might be some helpful information in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator.log that would shed some light on that.